# Unable to create private queue with MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I've been dealing with this problem since last week...none info in the internet that actually solve my problem....n I'm very very new to MSMQ

Whenever i try to create a new private queue....i get this error message
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/745d915a1d.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/745d915a1d.png)

and then when i check services ,the Message Queuing Triggers is not started..when i try to start it ...it gives me this error:-
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a6c368072c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a6c368072c.png)

then when i check the event viewer :-

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b8c751c71.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b8c751c71.png)

But still i cant create new queue....please help me...i've been stuck here for a week... :(

Comment: Could you please re-format yout post - the error messages are not visible.

Comment: Can't help you, error messages not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's ok guys...i'm able to create the q already :) through Computer Management

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\MyPrivateQueue");
```

More here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yka0xsf(v=vs.110).aspx